# Is it possible to prove that this integral is not attainable?

Tags: integration

So, I've been trying for some time to evaluate this integral:

$$I=K\int\left(\frac{x-h}{x}\right)^W\exp\left(\frac{Wh}{(x-h)}\right)\,dx$$

and a simplified version:

$$I=K\int\left(\frac{x-h}{h}\right)^W\exp\left(\frac{Wh}{(x-h)}\right)\,dx$$

Theoretically this cannot be done with integral by parts. I have tried other methods and even tried symbolic computation; all failed.

I am aiming to either solve it (obviously) or prove that it's not solvable. At this point I'm pretty much sure that it's not solvable, so I'm focusing my energy in proving that it can't be done.

How can one prove that?

Comment: See Wolfram alpha's attempt http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+z%5Ew+exp(W%2Fz)+dz

Comment: Use the gamma fiction here as illustrated in the Wolfram alpha solution

Comment: @ADITYA Gamma _fiction_?! (please, no offense intended, it's just a typo, or maybe even an auto-correction, and an amusing one at that).

Comment: There is no difference between the integral and the "simplified version", sorry. You're right that there is no closed form for the antiderivative, but why would you need one? You can always compute it numerically.

Comment: @ Professor Vector that's a auto- correction "NO offence intended" - None taken Sir...

Comment: @ProfessorVector I thought the denominator would make a difference. And I need an analytical solution in order to imposed a boundary condition in another problem.

Comment: @ProfessorVector In fact, according to Wolfram Alpha the simplified version can be integrated, while the original one cannot.

Comment: That may well be, but in your question, people still see two identical expressions, and that might prevent meaningful answers.